# Using backboneJS + requireJS + textJS in phonegap

Tags: html

Updated my previous question:

Is it possible to use the backbone.js + require.js + text.js in phone gap application.

I am having a solution which is implemented in backbone.js, require.js bootstrap.js.
is it possible to run this in phonegap

Because i'm having a application that is build in backbone.js which in turn uses requrieJS, textJS for loading the html fragments asynchronously. (XHR - XmlHttpRequests)

Because of this asynchronous call, it is unable to execute locally and needs to be hosted in a server.

In this case, is it possible for me to use this html5 solution directly in phonegap. where it needs to be run locally. ]

Or is it possible to use JQM for making asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1):

The code clearly suggest that you have a missing dependency. Offline doesn't really play a role here, your code won't work online or off. If it does either way, then you have discrepancy between these two :)

Comment: thanks for comment @angela, but the problem here is, when i am hosting it in tomcat server/ iis server. the code works fine with out the including the scripts mentioned here. when I'm trying to open the index.html page in the app directory statically, it not working and it is missing the architecture dependency. for that i have included all the possible js files in the index.html itself. i am in a confusion, whether the code will work with backbone.js code structure statically, so that i can implement the same in phone gap and have executable for all phone environments.

Comment: Then I would say that some other script is definitely dynamically inserting some dependency that you have missed. Or the directory is not readable for some reason. Sorry can't be more of help, this is not really an error programmatically.